# Как сделать проверку заполнения одного из полей?

Tags: jquery

Есть форма, валидация происходит через плагин jquery validation plugin.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="profile_form" action="#" method="post">
                <div class="field_block">
                    <p>E-mail: <span>*</span></p>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" value="victorpavloff@gmail.com">
                </div>
                <div class="field_block">
                    <p class="payment_system_title">Кошельки для выплат: <span>*</span></p>
                    <div class="error_text">Укажите минимум один кошелек</div>
                    <div class="payment_system_block clearfix">
                        <div class="payment_system yandex_money">Яндекс.Деньги</div>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="yandex_money">
                    </div>
                    <div class="payment_system_block clearfix">
                        <div class="payment_system qiwi">Qiwi</div>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="qiwi">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field_block">
                    <div class="text_block clearfix">
                        <p>Введите пароль: <span>*</span></p>
                        <div class="change_button"><span class="js-change_button">Изменить пароль</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="new_password">
                    <div class="field_block">
                        <p>Новый пароль: <span>*</span></p>
                        <input class="field new_password1" type="password" name="new_password1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field_block">
                        <p>Повторите пароль: <span>*</span></p>
                        <input class="field new_password2" type="password" name="new_password2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button">Сохранить изменения</button>
            </form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".profile_form").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true, 
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            new_password1: {
                required: true
            },
            new_password2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: { 
            email: {
                required: false, 
                email: false
            },
            password: {
                required: false
            },
            new_password1: {
                required: false
            },
            new_password2: {
                required: false
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            sendForm(form);
        }
    });
```

Как сделать проверку полей кошельков, если должно быть заполнено одно из полей на выбор?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($('input[name="yandex_money"]').val() || $('input[name="qiwi"]').val()) {
            // code
        }
```

На ванильном:

```
if (document.getElementsByName('yandex_money')[0].value || document.getElementsByName('qiwi')[0].value) {
// code
    }
```

Comment: Нужно через плагин

Comment: Даешь на каждую кнопку по плагину! =)